# Can't work on my java projects in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I used to work in Eclipse Luna and had many projects in my workspace. Then I decided to start coding for Android and downloaded the ADT bundle from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i#download). I imported my Luna workspace and it worked fine. However, whenever I open a class I get **cannot be resolved** errors everywhere on what used to be flawless code. What difference in packages is causing this? Why can't I write and compile Java in Juno?

Note that I don't see the errors in the package explorer on the left:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by imported your Luna workspace?

Comment: When it asked for default workspace, I pointed to my old Luna one/

Comment: Have you tried "clean" and "build" ?

Comment: I created a new workspace with Juno and then File > imported the old existing projects. Still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your jdk is missing or incorrect. Check in ur build path of the project. Your jre is probably still referencing the old location.

Comment: I created a new workspace with Juno and imported old projects, still getting the same type of errors.

Comment: I still think its ur jRE issue..Create a new java project in this workspace and create a new test class with some printlns. If this class works fine, then compare the JRE used for this project vs JRE on ur imported projects.

Comment: I found out that placing the old .java files in my new workspace and then removing the package line of code at the top does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new workspace and import your project folder by folder, omitting the folders  generated by  eclipse for the workspace to function properly.

for todo this:
file>import>android>android exsisting proyect

Comment: My older projects aren't about Android at all. But I'm going to create a new workspace anyway.

Answer (score 0):

select your project -> properties(Alt+Enter) ->Java Build Path -> Order and Export-> make sure android 4.1.1 or your target os Checkbok is selected.
[image]

if not then select click okay
clean and rebuild the project.
hope you will get your solution.

Comment: Ok, I moved JRE to top position and checked it. Errors still here. Plus I don't see Android 4.2.2 (or any version of it as a matter of fact) available for import, even though I got the bundle, which includes it, SDK is supposed to be installed already.

Comment: also check in properties Android->check sdk.

Comment: You can move workspaces to newer releases. There's no promise that everything will work taking them or their projects in the other direction.